# How to get AD group membership for list of users in CSV file?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I can get AD group information for a single user using this:

get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership john.doe -Server domain.com | select name |  Export-CSV -Path c:\temp\user.txt

What I need to do is get the AD group membership for say 100 employees.   How can I replace the user john.doe here and have it import a CSV file instead?

thanks

EDIT:   I think I got it to work using this PoweShell script:

Get-Content C:\temp\users.txt | ForEach-Object {
try {
foreach($group in Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ -Server domain.com) {
[pscustomobject]@{
UserName = $_
MemberOf = $group.Name
}
}
}
catch {
Write-Warning $_
}
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: You can do it without any loops with `GC C:\Temp\users.txt -pipelinevariable User|Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership| Select @{l='UserName';e={$User}},Name|Export-Csv C:\temp\results.csv -NoType`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think I got it to work using this PoweShell script:

Get-Content C:\temp\users.txt | ForEach-Object { try { foreach($group in Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ -Server domain.com) { [pscustomobject]@{ UserName = $_ MemberOf = $group.Name } } } catch { Write-Warning $_ } } | Export-Csv c:\temp\results.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the code blocks in your posts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).